# Fix memory leak in for loop

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, rcpp

I have issues with memory leaks on a C++ function that I have sourced into R through Rcpp. This result in a sudden abortion of my R session, without returning any specific error message.

What is weird to me is that if in `function_test` I move `double lower =1;` and `double upper = value2;` inside the for loop and edited them by also adding 'i':  `double lower =1 + i;` and `double upper = value2 + i;` the function works without aborting my R session.

The code below is sourced in R using the function `sourceCpp` from `Rcpp` R package. I run the function with the following values:

R function:

```
function_test(value1=4000, value2=4000, alpha = 5e-04)
```

C++ code sourced in R:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]
#define EIGEN_PERMANENTLY_DISABLE_STUPID_WARNINGS
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <RcppNumerical.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace Numer;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double func1(double t, double alpha, double beta){

  double term1 = (( 2.0 * log(t - 0.5)) + 1) / 25.0;

  int N;
      if (t == 1 || t == 2) {
      N = 2;
      }else{
      if (t <= 44) {
      N = t;
      }else{
      N = 44;
      }
      }

  NumericVector term_up(N);
  term_up[0] = 0;
  term_up[1] = term1;
  double res = std::accumulate(term_up.begin(), term_up.end(), 0.0);
  double int_final = (1/(25.0*t)) * (1 - (0.96)*res);
  return int_final;
}

class Func1PDF: public Func
{
private:
   double alpha;
   double beta;
public:
    Func1PDF(double alpha_, double beta_) : alpha(alpha_), beta(beta_) {}

    double operator()(const double& t) const{
        return func1(t, alpha, beta);
    }
  };

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  double integrate_func(double lower, double upper, double alpha, double beta)
  {

      Func1PDF f(alpha, beta);
      double err_est;
      int err_code;
      const double res = integrate(f, lower, upper, err_est, err_code);
      return res;
  }



  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  NumericVector function_test(double value1, double value2, double alpha) {

  NumericVector res(value1);
  double lower = 1;
  double upper = value2;
  for(int i=1;i<=value1;i++){
    double beta = i;
 res[i-1] = integrate_func(lower, upper, alpha, beta);

  }
  return res;

  }
```

Comment: how do you know that one has a leak and the other not? what is `integrate_func` ?

Comment: Because when I use the first one R crashes, whereas with the second function I do get an output. The `integrate_func` is a bit over complicated to be posted here, but if you are available to have a look at it I can post it in the question.

Comment: a crash is not necessarily caused by a leak, actually thats unlikely unless you run out of memory. Please try to post a [mcve]. If the problem can be reproduced without `integrate_func` it needs not be part of the mre

Comment: You are giving different values to `lower` and `upper` in the second code snippet, so anything could change. As we don't know what `integrate_func` does with its passed values, we can't really say much more.

Comment: Ok, I tried some other function and it seems that the error cannot be reproduced with a simpler function. I will need to post the integrate_func. I apologise in advance for the long function (perhaps).

Comment: I have updated it, but it is still not reproducible. Please let me know if you prefer to have the complete body of the fucntions.

Comment: `integrate_func` is just a wrapper for `integrate` and `Func1PDF` is just a wrapper for `func1`. TL;DR: What is `func1` and `integrate` ?

Comment: I have added func1. It depends from another function 'other_func'. Integrate is a function from the namespace Numer. I hope this help.

Comment: Just like your previous question asked yesterday, this contains too much code, and lacks focus. See for example [this piece on _minimally verifiable complete examples_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "how to use, for instance, namespace 'std' to avoid issues of memory allocation?" that makes no sense. Using any namespace won't fix anything, that's not how it works. The code you posted doesn't indicate any problems with memory allocation, why do you think that is the case? Does your system runs out of memory? What is the message you get when R crashes? And foremost give us a good piece of code that reproduces your problem so we can try it ourselves. Right now what you posted won't compile and due to poor formatting is even hard to read. What is `NumericVector`?

Comment: I have just updated the full code. When R crashes I do not get any informative message..it just opens up a window saying that 'R session aborted: R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated'

Comment: @MichałKaczorowski  This is in the context of C++ use from R which our Rcpp package facilitates.  `Rcpp::NumericVector` is a zero-copy instance of a vector in R and _e.g_ `Rcpp::cppFunction("double mySum(Rcpp::NumericVector x) { return Rcpp::sum(x); }")` builds a quick demo / check function `mySum`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm sorry for my code. I will try to make it simpler and reproducible, as you suggested.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have edited my code, by reducing it as much as possible, while also leading R to crash.